# Heroku: Python Django deployment suddenly failing

Tags: python, django, heroku, heroku-cli

I deployed my app this morning all fine, it has been running for months, I have just tried to deploy a change to two HTML template (nothing else has changed in GIT). Heroku is suddenly failing with the below

```
-----> Python app detected

 !     Requested runtime (python-3.6.10) is not available for this stack (heroku-18).
 !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

I can't even see anywhere I've specified a python version in Django, not in requirements.txt, but nothing has changed in this respect for months on the apps?

Any ideas greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In the article it links in your error trace it states that they support runtime python-3.6.11 meanwhile it appears your application is still on python-3.6.10. They probably upgraded the version of python they support.